# Anchor tag is not being recognized when inserted into a dynamically generated cell of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstl

I'm trying to insert an anchor tag inside a cell of an html table. Below is the code, somehow the  tag is not being recognized and I do not get a hyperlink for that cell. What is wrong with this syntax ?

```
    $("#tranTbodyId").append('<tr><td><a href='pageContext.request.contextPath'+"/FciDetailDescription.spr">'+ key+ '</a></td><td>' + value.tradeDate+
```

Please provide your suggestions. Thanks all.

Comment: syntax error close `</tr>` properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some incorrect quote characters

```
$("#tranTbodyId").append('<tr><td><a href=' + pageContext.request.contextPath + '"/FciDetailDescription.spr">' + key + '</a></td></tr>');
```

[Check the working Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fj92V/1/)

Note: to get the value of `pageContext.request.contextPath` it may need to be

```
var path = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}";
```

in which case it would be

```
$("#tranTbodyId").append('<tr><td><a href=' + path + '/Fcipage.spr>' + key + '</a></td>... '
```

Comment: Thanks all for the prompt response!!! But strangely, both the above syntax is not working. I'm using an inbuilt browser provided by RAD 8.0 and also tried in IE 8.0. Please help me to solve this aproblem

Comment: Did you check the fiddle Chakravathy added? - works fine for me - but I know nothing about RAD 8.0

Comment: yes I checked the fiddle, it's working. But I'm not sure why the same syntax is not working for me. When I remove the <A> tag from the piece of html I pasted in my above question, the data is displayed on the page. That is,only when this <A> tag inserted within those quotes causes the jquery not to work.

Comment: I suspect that due to the values of `pageContext.request.contextPath` and/or `key`. Before the line of code above, add `var p = pageContext.request.contextPath; var k = key;` and check what they return (one or both is probably `undefined`!)

Comment: You probably want this: `var path = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}"; and then `$("#tranTbodyId").append('<tr><td><a href=' + path + '"/Fci.....`. Let me know if it works and I'll update answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I followed your second suggestion and it WORKED!!-  var path = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}" and  $("#tranTbodyId").append('<tr><td><a href=' + path + '/Fcipage.spr>' + key + '</a></td>...  Only change is I removed the double quotes before and after '/Fcipage.spr' instead just went with single quotes because when "" was present it inserted the escape char %22 which was not desirable for me.

Answer (score 2):

There is syntax error, it should be used like this

```
             $("#tranTbodyId").append('<tr><td><a href="'+pageContext.request.contextPath+'/FciDetailDescription.spr">'+ key+ '</a></td><td>' + value.tradeDate);
```

[Check the working Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fj92V/1/)